# Infragistics: Attach EventHandle to UltraTreeView not using designer

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultratree

I am creating a UltraTree dynamically. I need to attach click event to the nodes. When I attempt to do this in the same fashion as my other controls that I created using the designer, I get an error on the attachment statement:

No overload for 'ruleTree_AfterSelect' matches delegate 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.AfterNodeSelectEventHandler'

Here's my Handler name and attachment statement:

```
 private void ruleTree_AfterSelect(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.NodeEventArgs e)

 //Attaching to handle to tree event
 tree.AfterSelect += new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.AfterNodeSelectEventHandler(ruleTree_AfterSelect);
```

Any ideas why Visual Studio allows itself to attach handlers in this manner but throws an error when doing it through code?

Is there a file or background process that Visual Studio runs to handle this when adding events through design mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no hidden code to handle adding events.
You could check by yourself in the method **InitializeComponent()**

However your problem is different.
The correct signature for an **UltraTree.AfterSelect** event is

```
private void ruleTree_AfterSelect(object sender, 
             Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.SelectEventArgs e)
{
.....
}
```

Comment: Correcting the Argument type fixed the issue. Thanks Steve.